# Creating a Symbian's like application menu at S60

Tags: qt, layout, menu, symbian, nokia

I wanted to make an app which is when started it shows a menu. It is just like when you open a Messaging app in S60. Here is a screenshot.

[image: what i want]

How do I make it? I have tried to make the centralWidget of the QMainWindow as QMenu, and adding QAction to the QMenu. But when I'm running it, the app don't show anything. And I have tried to make the QMenu using QMenuBar. And it is show okay. But I can't use the up/down key to select menu in the device. And when I press the options key (Qt::PositiveSoftKey), the menubar shows up too. And I didn't even add that to menuBar() which is owned by QMainWindow.

Here is my first code:

```
QAction* act1= new QAction(tr("act1"),this);
QObject::connect(tes,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(close()));
QAction* act2= new QAction(tr("act2"),this);
QObject::connect(tes,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(close()));
QMenu* menu = new QMenu(this);
menu->addAction(act1);
menu->addAction(act2);
setCentralWidget(menu);
```

And it shows nothing at the apps.

And here is my second try:

```
Qt Code: Switch view
QAction* act1= new QAction(tr("act1"),this);
QObject::connect(tes,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(close()));
QAction* act2= new QAction(tr("act2"),this);
QObject::connect(tes,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(close()));
QMenuBar* menubar = new QMenuBar(this);
QMenu* menu = menubar->addMenu(tr("menu"));
menu->addAction(act1);
menu->addAction(act2);
setCentralWidget(menu);
```

It shows the menu. But when I deploy to the device, I can't use the keypad to select the menu. And at the simulator, if I click other place than the QAction item, the menu lost.

I am using another approach by using QPushButton with Vertical Layout. Here is the code:

```
QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
scrollArea->setWidget(centralWidget);
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
setCentralWidget(scrollArea);

QVBoxLayout* centralLayout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton(tr("button 1"));
QPushButton* button2 = new QPushButton(tr("button 2"));
centralLayout->addWidget(button1);
centralLayout->addWidget(button2);
centralLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
button1->setFocus();
```

Here it's look:

[image: 8button]

Okay, and that's look good enough. But if that's have 8 button. If it is only have 2 button, it looks like this:

[image: 2button]

looks kind of weird, huh? Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the UI that you're trying to replicate is a list of options, so, why don't try to create the UI based on a list widget?

Asumming that you're going to use a list, you have to options from which you have to choose based on your needs and your app requirements:

- Qt Widgets: Available in all the Qt supported Plataforms. Created for desktop and works great on it, but in feel strange on mobile devices. Take a look to the [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qlistwidget.html) and [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qlistview.html).
- [Qt Quick:](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtquick.html) It isn't available for S40 phones or S60 3rd edition, not available for non-touch phones, basically. Created for "touch enabled UI's", it doesn't offer a stable set of widgets (buttons, comboboxes) yet, but it offers a set of primitives (like rectangles or images) that gives you a lot of freedom to create your UI's and it looks pretty good. I think that this is what Lucian used to create the UI from his answer.
  This examples could be of particular interest: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/all-examples.html

Run the [QtDemo](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtdemo.html) to see all the examples live!

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Adding example of QListWidget

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("Qt.png"), QString("Item %1").arg(i));
        ui->listWidget->insertItem(i, item);
    }
    ui->listWidget->setIconSize(QSize(64, 64));

    connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));
}

void MainWindow::onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "", QString("%1 pressed").arg(item->text()));
}
```

[image: QListWidget on Qt SDK Emulator]

Comment: can you give me an example using QListWidget or QListView? I need to use it for S60 without touch. I have already tried QListWidget, but it needs QListWidgetItem to use it. I tried to inherit QPushButton and QListWidgetItem but it is not working well.

Comment: There's no need to inherit from QPushButton, the QListWidget can emit signals to inform that it was clicked or selected. This is shown in the example that I've added.

Comment: I just deploy it to the device. The view is good. But I can't click it. :( Do you have any idea? At the simulator it's work well. :(

Comment: @dieend Sorry, I have only deployed in touch phones.
Maybe the central key of the nav pad generates another type of event than clicked, try to connect other signals like onItemSelected or onItemPressed, check the doc for the correct names.

Comment: it is itemActivated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score -1):

You have all the freedom in the world to create your layout the way you like. Want those buttons closer together? Want them centered in the view?

The attached image took me 30 seconds to create and looks already decent (according to my pour designer skills).

[image]